# how to pass variable within different function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two different function in vue app method which has a restriction in some of their code which cannot be combine. but in the same time I need some variable in function `f1` to be use in function `f2`.

```
<script>
let item1;
export default {
  data(): return{},
  methods: {
    function f1(){
      const item1 = value1;
    },
    function f2(){
      const item2 = item1;
      console.log(item2);
    }
  },
  mounted: {
    this.f1();
    this.f2();
  }
}
```

this is an example code, I need the `item1` value is read by item2. the value of `item1` only can be retrieve from function `f1`, and function `f2` need that value. Is there anything to make the variable become global?

Comment: Things declared inside functions are not available inside other functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually the same problem I faced.

Then I figure out that  tag in vue is almost same as  tag in html. You can always write your own js code and choose which part you want to export as default which is exact component definition.

So you can easily do this to access variables from different methods, watches, computed or even data.

```
<template>
    <div>abc</div>
</template>
<script>
let item1

export default {
    data(): return{},
    methods: {
        function f1(){
            item1 = value1;
        },
        function f2(){
            const item2 = item1;
            console.log(item2);
        }
    },
    mounted: {
        this.f1();
        this.f2();
    }
}
</script>
```

Just avoiding to use `const` to declare another local variable `item1` which is only available in that method.
You will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this

```js
// Global Scope you can access these items
let item1;
let item2;

function one() {
  // function scope can access items on the global scope
  // but anything defined within here will not be accessible by the global scope
  item1 = 'item1';
}

function two() {
  // function scope
  item2 = item1;
  console.log(item2);
}

one();
two();
```

The reason why your example didn't work is due to [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

Your vue.js file should look like this

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      item1: null,
      item2: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    f1() {
      this.item1 = 'item1';
    },
    f2() {
      this.item2 = this.item1;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.f1();
    this.f2();
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i understand how this solution works in pure js. but it;s come a problem in my vuejs. where i should declare the `let item1;` should be. before this i've tried to declare the variable once i start the script, but did not work. the function should be in methods: {} part,

Comment: @KhairulHabib please see my updated answer, you need to store your variables in the data() object

Comment: i also has try this and it's return null value

Comment: i've succeed using some new method for this case where i'm call `this.f2(this.item1)` in function f1. thank you for your sharing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let item1;

function f1() {
  item1 = "value1";
}

function f2() {
  const item2 = item1;
  console.log(item2);
}
f1();
f2();
```

You must declare a global variable to use it in different functions.

Comment: ya, it can work on it in pure JS,but it's come with problem in vue.js. i can see the logics in this snippet and actually i have tried that way before in my vue app but did not work. where the right place to declared the variable in vue script? before i have declared it once i start my script, and the function in the method section `methods: {}` but still the value can't be read.

Answer (score 0):

define your var "item1" on data and use it in any func see this example

```
<script>
 export default {
data() {
    return {
        item1: ''
    };
},
methods: {
    f1() {
         this.item1 = value1;
    },
    f2() {
        const item2 = this.item1;
        console.log(item2);
    }
  }
 };
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

this code work perfectly which i'm calling second function to be active by using first function.

```
export default {
  data(): return{},
  methods: {
    f1(){
      const item1 = value1;
      this.f2(item1)
    },
    f2(item1){
      const item2 = item1;
      console.log(item2);
    }
  },
  mounted: {
    this.f1();
  }
}
```